# How to submit two copies of same iOS app to the itunesconnect (app store)

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode6.3, ios8.3

Thanks,

I want to upload the two copies iPhone application to the app store.

1) One with iwatch extension included.

2) One without iwatch extension.

If I include iwatch extension. I can't keep the deployment target below 8.0.

Is it possible and allowed by apple. can I keep the bundle identifiers same or I should change it? 
Do I need to create two App IDs for the app?

Please help me with any other setting to change.

My deployment target without iwatch extension is iOS 7+.

Comment: Every app should have the different Bundle Identifier. Just make two apps and submit that will work simply.

Comment: ya you can submit two copies but make sure not to submit both on same day.Ya you  should change bundle identifier ,app id and other things...

Comment: Thanks Manpreet and Sudhan for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, that should be possible.
Note that you should **change the Bundle Identifier** as every app needs to have a unique one. I would also recommend to **change the name** (I believe you *have to* do that anyways) to show the users which one is w/ and w/o AppleWatch Extension.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. You cannot have the same app in the AppStore that has the same bundle identifier.

Also, is there a real pressing need to have that backward compatibility (apart from wanting to have the greatest number of phones able to download your app)? Because if not, then maybe consider that deployment > 8.0 is enough.

Comment: It enlarges the user community. Many people still have < iOS 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for suggestions and answers.

We can do it. These are the steps we need to follow.

1) Just we have to create new app id for the iPhone application with watch extension.

```
In case we are doing it manually.
```

2)we need to create two more app ids one for watchapp and other for watchkitextension as a target.

```
for eg. the app id is com.appname

The appid for the watch extension would be com.appname.watchkitextension
The app id for the watch app would be com.appname.watchkitapp

Both will be considered different app ids.
```

3) We need enable the all the three app ids with same App Group

4) keep deployment target of the watchextension and watchkitapp target as 8.2. And for iPhone companion app we can keep it 8.0

4) Generate the app store distribution provisioning provisioning profiles (can keep same distribution certificate) in case want to upload to the iTunes stores for beta testing or app review.

and We are done. This will successfully archieve the app bundle.

**Another way. : Just don't do it manually and let Xcode handle it**

Note : While developing app. When we add new target as watchkit. The new Xcode generates the app id for watch kit app and extension.

Just we can use it by refreshing provisioning profile from Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts. Select Account and refresh.  (Note : We need to configure the developer account with Xcode for that).

It will download and install the provisioning profile with Xcode.

And we can directly archieve the app bundle for app store submission by selecting the right provisioning profile